# Python BeautifulSoup - chars getting mangled when copied to new file

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have some html, that in browser reads:

`‎(239 × 340 pixels, file size: 29 KB, MIME type: image/jpeg)`

I can pull it out of the source html and throw it in a new html doc:-

```
file_details = self.soup.body.find("div", {"id": "file"})
self.new_soup.body.insert(3, file_details)
```

If I print the file_details item on into terminal, I can see the string I want.

when I render the new_soup html, I get:-

`â€Ž (239 Ã— 340 pixels, file size: 29 KB, MIME type: image/jpeg)`

looking at the resulting html, I can see that the extra chars have been added into into the tag.

I'm not sure where they are coming from, but at a guess I am either reading with a wrong encoding, or writing with a wrong encoding soomewhere

Any suggestions?

Comment: You may want to take look at BeautifulSoup documentation, more specifically ["Encodings"](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#encodings), ["Output encoding"](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#output-encoding).

Comment: Perfect. I was encoding as `utf-8`, should have been `latin-1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to iljau in the comments, I fixed it.

In my preparing to save statment I prettified with the wrong encoding.

Was:-

`html = soup.prettify("utf-8")`

fixed it becomes:-

`html = soup.prettify("latin-1")`